# fork with invalid command cause a memory leak in valgrind

Tags: c, linux, memory-leaks, valgrind

I have the following code which execute a non valid command within a fork.
The following code return a memory leak in valgrind.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdarg.h>
#include <errno.h>
#include <unistd.h>


int external_cmd(char **argv)
{
    int pid;

    if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
        return -1;

    if (pid == 0) {
        /* child */
        execvp(argv[0], argv);
        exit(0);

    } else if (pid < 0)
        return -1;

    int status;
    while (wait(&status) != pid);

    return 0;
}

int main ()
{
    char *argv[8] = {0};
    argv[0] = "tawtaw"; //<--------- invalid command
    argv[1] = "-a";

    char *mem = strdup("anychar");

    /* fork call */
    external_cmd(argv);

    free(mem);

   return(0);
}
```

executing the above code with valgrind return:

```
$ valgrind --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all ./test
==11573== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==11573== Copyright (C) 2002-2013, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==11573== Using Valgrind-3.10.1 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==11573== Command: ./test
==11573== 
==11574== 
==11574== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11574==     in use at exit: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==11574==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 0 frees, 8 bytes allocated
==11574== 
==11574== 8 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 1
==11574==    at 0x4C2AB80: malloc (in /usr/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-linux.so)
==11574==    by 0x4EBF729: strdup (strdup.c:42)
==11574==    by 0x400747: main (in /home/mohamed/Desktop/tech/test/test)
==11574== 
==11574== LEAK SUMMARY:
==11574==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11574==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11574==      possibly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11574==    still reachable: 8 bytes in 1 blocks
==11574==         suppressed: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11574== 
==11574== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11574== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
==11573== 
==11573== HEAP SUMMARY:
==11573==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==11573==   total heap usage: 1 allocs, 1 frees, 8 bytes allocated
==11573== 
==11573== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==11573== 
==11573== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==11573== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

**NOTE:** If I execute the code with a valid command "ls" in stead of "tawtaw" then valgring will not return memory leak.

What I m missing ?

Comment: What's wrong with just terminating the child process after a failed `execvp()`, as you have with the `exit(0)`? It seems like it would actually be a little faster than modifying the heap and then terminating. The OS will free _all_ the process's resources either way. It's not a leak where  you want to keep going, but have a memory problem. And it's not like you're using shared memory, so you're not affecting other processes or wasting a shared resource.

Answer (score 2):

That is expected. When `execve()`  can't execute command, it returns control to your code, and than you exit and never free memory from `strdup()`.

When `execve` succeeds, the whole file image is replaced, and nothing remains of the memory allocated with `strdup()`.

Comment: the exit is in child process and not in the parent. And you can seen in the valgrind log that the memory of strdup is freed in the parent process

Comment: Yes, it's freed in the parent (11573), but it's not freed in the child process (11574).

Comment: @MOHAMED, but when you forked, all the memory was duplicated in the child, including the one allocated with `strdup()` - and this you didn't free in the child. This is exactly what valgrind is reporting here.

Comment: Notice the numbers on the left side of the valgrind output. That is the pid of the process it is reporting on.

Comment: How to fix a such issue. I can not free all the memory duplicated from the parent in the child it's too much and not proper

Comment: I don't see any issue.

Comment: @ikegami but valgrind is indicating a memory leak in the child

Comment: But it's expected.

Comment: @ikegami are there a way to catch the command error and force exeve to return without eroor exit

Comment: @ikegami or are there other function than execve that free memory before the error exit

Comment: 1) `exec*` doesn't exit. 2) All memory is freed on exit, no matter how you exit.

Comment: @ikegami sorry it's execvp and not execve

Comment: None of the `exec*` exit. As mentioned earlier, they replace the program being run by the process with another.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't care about this "leak", because it's just your process terminating abnormally. You are not expected to carefully free your resources when you need to just print an error message and exit. The OS will free all outstanding resources.

If you are still concerned about this for some reason, try replacing `exit(0)` with `return -1;`.  In a real program you would never use `exit`, but only normal return paths that free allocated resources. In C++, use RAII and throw an exception when you need to exit abnormally. Here is your program converted to RAII style:

```
#include <cstdlib>
#include <cstdarg>
#include <cerrno>
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdexcept>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

// This function should be standard in some kind of POSIX C++ library
void execvp(const std::string& program, const std::vector<std::string>& args)
{
    std::vector<const char*> real_argv(args.size()+1);
    for (const std::string& s : args)
        real_argv.push_back(s.c_str());
    real_argv.push_back(nullptr);
    // have to use const_cast because of the broken const model of C
    execvp(program.c_str(), const_cast<char**>(real_argv.data()));
    throw std::runtime_error((std::string("Could not execvp ") + args[0]).c_str());
}

int external_cmd(const std::string& program, const std::vector<std::string>& args)
{
    int pid;

    if ((pid = fork()) == -1)
        return -1;

    if (pid == 0) {
        /* child */
        execvp(program, args);

    } else if (pid < 0)
        return -1;

    int status;
    while (wait(&status) != pid);

    return 0;
}

int main ()
{
    try {
        std::vector<std::string> args;
        args.push_back("tawtaw");
        args.push_back("-a");

        std::string s("12345678"); // RAII

        /* fork call */
        external_cmd(args[0], args);

        return EXIT_SUCCESS;
    } catch (std::exception& e) {
        std::cerr << e.what() << ". Exiting.\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    } catch ( ... ) {
        std::cerr << "Unexpected error. OS message is: " << strerror(errno) << ". Exiting.\n";
        return EXIT_FAILURE;
    }
}
```

Comment: I look a solution for c. May be i have to remove the c++ tag

Comment: @MOHAMED Please use appropriate language tags next time. There is no prepackaged "solution" for C. You either free your memory yourself, or ignore the "leak".

Comment: return -1 solved the issue but the fork take time to finish