# C, Leak on fork without malloc

Tags: c, memory-management, memory-leaks, fork

I'm trying to understand how memory allocation work on fork, even on static or dynamic allocation. I've some trouble to understand some leaks as shown below.

With this program :

```
#include <unistd.h>
#include <sys/wait.h>

int     main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    pid_t pid;
    int     status;


    pid = fork();
    if (pid == 0)
        return (0);
    else
    {
        waitpid(pid, &status, 0);
        return (0);
    }
}
```

I'm getting this log file with valgrind :

```
==81268== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==81268== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==81268== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==81268== Command: ./a.out
==81268== Parent PID: 73556
==81268==
==81268== Syscall param msg->desc.port.name points to uninitialised byte(s)
==81268==    at 0x1003A834A: mach_msg_trap (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib)
==81268==    by 0x1003A7796: mach_msg (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib)
==81268==    by 0x1003A1485: task_set_special_port (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib)
==81268==    by 0x10053D10E: _os_trace_create_debug_control_port (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib)
==81268==    by 0x10053D458: _libtrace_init (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib)
==81268==    by 0x1000A69DF: libSystem_initializer (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==81268==    by 0x100018A1A: ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==81268==    by 0x100018C1D: ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==81268==    by 0x1000144A9: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==81268==    by 0x100014440: ImageLoader::recursiveInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, char const*, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==81268==    by 0x100013523: ImageLoader::processInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, unsigned int, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&, ImageLoader::UninitedUpwards&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==81268==    by 0x1000135B8: ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==81268==  Address 0x10488bc6c is on thread 1's stack
==81268==  in frame #2, created by task_set_special_port (???:)
==81268==
==81269==
==81269== HEAP SUMMARY:
==81269==     in use at exit: 28,557 bytes in 172 blocks
==81269==   total heap usage: 188 allocs, 16 frees, 34,701 bytes allocated
==81269==
==81269== 72 bytes in 3 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 31 of 55
==81269==    at 0x100098BF2: calloc (in /Users/simrossi/.brew/Cellar/valgrind/3.13.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==81269==    by 0x1005B1846: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==81269==    by 0x1005C4FE8: objc_object::sidetable_retainCount() (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==81269==    by 0x10000803B: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==81269==    by 0x100008255: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==81269==    by 0x1001FF00A: _dyld_objc_notify_register (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==81269==    by 0x1005B1074: _objc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==81269==    by 0x10019268D: _os_object_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==81269==    by 0x10019263A: libdispatch_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==81269==    by 0x1000A69D5: libSystem_initializer (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==81269==    by 0x100018A1A: ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==81269==    by 0x100018C1D: ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==81269==
==81269== 2,064 (16 direct, 2,048 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 51 of 55
==81269==    at 0x100098586: malloc (in /Users/simrossi/.brew/Cellar/valgrind/3.13.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==81269==    by 0x1004E9103: _nc_table_new (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib)
==81269==    by 0x1004E4FB5: _notify_init_globals (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib)
==81269==    by 0x1004F2AC0: _os_once (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib)
==81269==    by 0x1004F2A91: _os_alloc_once (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib)
==81269==    by 0x1004E50AD: _notify_fork_child (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib)
==81269==    by 0x1000A6B20: libSystem_atfork_child (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==81269==    by 0x10026F436: fork (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==81269==    by 0x100000F4A: main (in ./a.out)
==81269==
==81269== 2,064 (16 direct, 2,048 indirect) bytes in 1 blocks are definitely lost in loss record 52 of 55
==81269==    at 0x100098586: malloc (in /Users/simrossi/.brew/Cellar/valgrind/3.13.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==81269==    by 0x1004E9103: _nc_table_new (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib)
==81269==    by 0x1004E4FC6: _notify_init_globals (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib)
==81269==    by 0x1004F2AC0: _os_once (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib)
==81269==    by 0x1004F2A91: _os_alloc_once (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_platform.dylib)
==81269==    by 0x1004E50AD: _notify_fork_child (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib)
==81269==    by 0x1000A6B20: libSystem_atfork_child (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==81269==    by 0x10026F436: fork (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_c.dylib)
==81269==    by 0x100000F4A: main (in ./a.out)
==81269==
==81269== LEAK SUMMARY:
==81269==    definitely lost: 32 bytes in 2 blocks
==81269==    indirectly lost: 4,096 bytes in 2 blocks
==81269==      possibly lost: 72 bytes in 3 blocks
==81269==    still reachable: 200 bytes in 6 blocks
==81269==         suppressed: 24,157 bytes in 159 blocks
==81269== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==81269== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==81269==
==81269== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==81269== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==81269== ERROR SUMMARY: 5 errors from 4 contexts (suppressed: 13 from 13)
==81268==
==81268== HEAP SUMMARY:
==81268==     in use at exit: 18,127 bytes in 159 blocks
==81268==   total heap usage: 175 allocs, 16 frees, 24,271 bytes allocated
==81268==
==81268== 72 bytes in 3 blocks are possibly lost in loss record 26 of 42
==81268==    at 0x100098BF2: calloc (in /Users/simrossi/.brew/Cellar/valgrind/3.13.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==81268==    by 0x1005B1846: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==81268==    by 0x1005C4FE8: objc_object::sidetable_retainCount() (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==81268==    by 0x10000803B: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==81268==    by 0x100008255: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==81268==    by 0x1001FF00A: _dyld_objc_notify_register (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==81268==    by 0x1005B1074: _objc_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==81268==    by 0x10019268D: _os_object_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==81268==    by 0x10019263A: libdispatch_init (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==81268==    by 0x1000A69D5: libSystem_initializer (in /usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib)
==81268==    by 0x100018A1A: ImageLoaderMachO::doModInitFunctions(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==81268==    by 0x100018C1D: ImageLoaderMachO::doInitialization(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==81268==
==81268== LEAK SUMMARY:
==81268==    definitely lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==81268==    indirectly lost: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==81268==      possibly lost: 72 bytes in 3 blocks
==81268==    still reachable: 200 bytes in 6 blocks
==81268==         suppressed: 17,855 bytes in 150 blocks
==81268== Reachable blocks (those to which a pointer was found) are not shown.
==81268== To see them, rerun with: --leak-check=full --show-leak-kinds=all
==81268==
==81268== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==81268== Use --track-origins=yes to see where uninitialised values come from
==81268== ERROR SUMMARY: 2 errors from 2 contexts (suppressed: 12 from 12)
```

I do not understand where those 32 bytes and 4096 bytes who leaks are coming from ? Is it coming from the standard library, I saw something like that on stackoverflow. I'm on Mac OS Sierra x86_64.

EDIT: I'm not getting any leaks if I don't fork, it seem to be related to the function call.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [fork with invalid command cause a memory leak in valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41126905/fork-with-invalid-command-cause-a-memory-leak-in-valgrind)

Comment: Don't get any leak on my Linux machine. Code looks fine except that I would use exit() instead of return.

Comment: Could be a macOS specific problem?

Comment: I'm actually not allocating any memory, that's a part of my problem

Comment: @Someprogrammerdude It's what i'm wondering

Comment: On Linux this program doesn't call `malloc` and friends at all. So this looks like a problem with the implementation of `fork` on Mac OS X.

Answer (score 0):

The start-up code for a program on macOS allocates quite a lot of memory that is never freed.  There is nothing you can do about the memory being allocated.  You can, however, tell Valgrind about the leaks and persuade it to ignore them.  I believe the `fork()` is immaterial — you'd probably see the leaks even without that.

You need to run a program such as this with options to generate suppressions, capture the suppressions in a file, and then (in future) run specifying the suppressions file you created.

You can see a worked example at [Valgrind shows memory leak with empty main without including headers](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36897737/15168).