# C, Valgrind free because of large allocation without any malloc

Tags: c, memory, valgrind

I'm writting a shell and I'm having trouble to perform memory check because valgrind is unable to run properly.

I'm getting an error like that (killing it myself) :

```
==19703== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==19703== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==19703== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==19703== Command: ./tmpsh
==19703==
--19703-- run: /usr/bin/dsymutil "./tmpsh"
==19703== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0xffffffff000, 0x120000000000) (defined)
==19703== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x140000000000, 0x200000000000) (defined)
==19703== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x120000000000, 0x140000000000) (noaccess)
[1]    19703 killed     valgrind --leak-check=yes ./tmpsh
```

It seem to have a huge allocation somewhere, I was able to produce a similar error message with a code like below.

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <limits.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stdio.h>


struct  test
{
    void    *val;
    void    *val1;
    void    *val2;
    void    *val3;

};

int     main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    int x;
    char    *ptr;

    x = 0;
    while (x++ < 500)
    {
        ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct test) * UINT_MAX);
        printf("%p\n", ptr);
        x++;
    }
    return (0);
}
```

With a valgrind output like that :

```
==22340== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==22340== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==22340== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==22340== Command: ./a.out
==22340==
==22340== Syscall param msg->desc.port.name points to uninitialised byte(s)
...
ImageLoader::runInitializers(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, ImageLoader::InitializerTimingList&) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==22340==  Address 0x10488bc8c is on thread 1's stack
==22340==  in frame #2, created by task_set_special_port (???:)
==22340==
==22340== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x259c3a040, 0x2259c3a020) (undefined)
0x259c3a040
==22340== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x2259c3b040, 0x4259c3b020) (undefined)
0x2259c3b040
...
```

But in this case, my program is running beacause I'm able to use printf.

So I remove all of my code and having a main like that to avoid malloc, but still getting the same error :

```
int     main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    t_hist  *history;
    int     status;

        status = 0;
    return (status);
}
```

My project is containing a large number of file and is linked with single static (.a) library.

Could this huge allocation come from valgrind ? Could it come from my project architecture ?
Thanks for helping

***FULL LOG after a couple of minutes, without killing it myself***

```
==22900== Memcheck, a memory error detector
==22900== Copyright (C) 2002-2017, and GNU GPL'd, by Julian Seward et al.
==22900== Using Valgrind-3.13.0 and LibVEX; rerun with -h for copyright info
==22900== Command: ./tmpsh
==22900==
==22900== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0xffffffff000, 0x120000000000) (defined)
==22900== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x140000000000, 0x200000000000) (defined)
==22900== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x120000000000, 0x140000000000) (noaccess)
==22900== Warning: set address range perms: large range [0x600000000000, 0x640000003000) (noaccess)
==22900== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==22900==    at 0x10018CFAD: __sanitizer::StackDepotReverseMap::StackDepotReverseMap() (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x100184FC8: __sanitizer::RegisterCommonFlags(__sanitizer::FlagParser*, __sanitizer::CommonFlags*) (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x10019C6DE: handleFunctionTypeMismatch(__ubsan::FunctionTypeMismatchData*, unsigned long, __ubsan::ReportOptions) (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x10019B2E6: handleShiftOutOfBoundsImpl(__ubsan::ShiftOutOfBoundsData*, unsigned long, unsigned long, __ubsan::ReportOptions) (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x10019C9A8: __ubsan_handle_nonnull_return_v1 (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x10017DC0D: wrap__Znam (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x1001764DF: __sanitizer_annotate_contiguous_container (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x101411846: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x101424FE8: objc_object::sidetable_retainCount() (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x10003E03B: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==22900==    by 0x10003E255: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==22900==    by 0x10105F00A: _dyld_objc_notify_register (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==22900==
==22900== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==22900==    at 0x10018CFAD: __sanitizer::StackDepotReverseMap::StackDepotReverseMap() (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x10018508D: __sanitizer::RegisterCommonFlags(__sanitizer::FlagParser*, __sanitizer::CommonFlags*) (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x10019C6DE: handleFunctionTypeMismatch(__ubsan::FunctionTypeMismatchData*, unsigned long, __ubsan::ReportOptions) (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x10019B2E6: handleShiftOutOfBoundsImpl(__ubsan::ShiftOutOfBoundsData*, unsigned long, unsigned long, __ubsan::ReportOptions) (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x10019C9A8: __ubsan_handle_nonnull_return_v1 (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x10017DC0D: wrap__Znam (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x1001764DF: __sanitizer_annotate_contiguous_container (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x101411846: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x101424FE8: objc_object::sidetable_retainCount() (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x10003E03B: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==22900==    by 0x10003E255: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==22900==    by 0x10105F00A: _dyld_objc_notify_register (in /usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib)
==22900==
==22900== Invalid read of size 1
==22900==    at 0x100120809: __asan::asan_calloc(unsigned long, unsigned long, __sanitizer::BufferedStackTrace*) (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x100176130: __asan_poison_stack_memory (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x101414054: freeBuckets(NXHashTable*, int) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x101413F15: _NXHashRehashToCapacity (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x101413E50: NXHashInsert (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x101413B0D: NXCreateHashTableFromZone (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x1014139CE: NXCreateHashTable (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x1014138CE: NXCreateMapTableFromZone (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x101413878: NXCreateMapTableFromZone (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x101412350: __sel_registerName(char const*, int, int) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x101412062: sel_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x1014119CA: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==22900==  Address 0x104a001a0 is 16 bytes before a block of size 24 alloc'd
==22900==    at 0x1000CEDB5: malloc_zone_calloc (in /Users/simrossi/.brew/Cellar/valgrind/3.13.0/lib/valgrind/vgpreload_memcheck-amd64-darwin.so)
==22900==    by 0x101413E13: NXHashInsert (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x101413B0D: NXCreateHashTableFromZone (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x1014139CE: NXCreateHashTable (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x1014138CE: NXCreateMapTableFromZone (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x101413878: NXCreateMapTableFromZone (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x101412350: __sel_registerName(char const*, int, int) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x101412062: sel_init (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x1014119CA: map_images_nolock (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x101424FE8: objc_object::sidetable_retainCount() (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x10003E03B: dyld::notifyBatchPartial(dyld_image_states, bool, char const* (*)(dyld_image_states, unsigned int, dyld_image_info const*), bool, bool) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==22900==    by 0x10003E255: dyld::registerObjCNotifiers(void (*)(unsigned int, char const* const*, mach_header const* const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*), void (*)(char const*, mach_header const*)) (in /usr/lib/dyld)
==22900==
=================================================================
==22900==ERROR: AddressSanitizer: attempting free on address which was not malloc()-ed: 0x000104a001b0 in thread T0
==22900== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==22900==    at 0x10018CFAD: __sanitizer::StackDepotReverseMap::StackDepotReverseMap() (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x10019BFCC: handleFloatCastOverflow(void*, unsigned long, __ubsan::ReportOptions) (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x10019BAA1: __ubsan_handle_missing_return (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x100193D74: __sanitizer_reset_coverage (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x10019AEA9: handleShiftOutOfBoundsImpl(__ubsan::ShiftOutOfBoundsData*, unsigned long, unsigned long, __ubsan::ReportOptions) (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x10019A827: handleNegateOverflowImpl(__ubsan::OverflowData*, unsigned long, __ubsan::ReportOptions) (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x100128188: __asan::ErrorStringFunctionMemoryRangesOverlap::Print() (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x10017B5C0: __asan::SetMallocContextSize(unsigned int) (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x10017A70C: __asan::AsanInitInternal() (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x100176130: __asan_poison_stack_memory (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x101414054: freeBuckets(NXHashTable*, int) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x101413F15: _NXHashRehashToCapacity (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==22900==
==22900== Conditional jump or move depends on uninitialised value(s)
==22900==    at 0x10019C1E7: handleFloatCastOverflow(void*, unsigned long, __ubsan::ReportOptions) (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x10019BAA1: __ubsan_handle_missing_return (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x100193D74: __sanitizer_reset_coverage (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x10019AEA9: handleShiftOutOfBoundsImpl(__ubsan::ShiftOutOfBoundsData*, unsigned long, unsigned long, __ubsan::ReportOptions) (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x10019A827: handleNegateOverflowImpl(__ubsan::OverflowData*, unsigned long, __ubsan::ReportOptions) (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x100128188: __asan::ErrorStringFunctionMemoryRangesOverlap::Print() (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x10017B5C0: __asan::SetMallocContextSize(unsigned int) (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x10017A70C: __asan::AsanInitInternal() (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x100176130: __asan_poison_stack_memory (in /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x101414054: freeBuckets(NXHashTable*, int) (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x101413F15: _NXHashRehashToCapacity (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x101413E50: NXHashInsert (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==22900==
atos cannot load symbols for process 22900.
==22900==WARNING: Can't read from symbolizer at fd 5
atos cannot load symbols for process 22900.
==22900==WARNING: Can't read from symbolizer at fd 5
atos cannot load symbols for process 22900.
==22900==WARNING: Can't read from symbolizer at fd 5
atos cannot load symbols for process 22900.
==22900==WARNING: Can't read from symbolizer at fd 5
==22900==WARNING: Failed to use and restart external symbolizer!
    #0 0x100176066 in wrap_free (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x59066)
atos cannot load symbols for process 22900.
    #1 0x101414054 in freeBuckets(NXHashTable*, int) (/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x4054)
    #2 0x101413f15 in _NXHashRehashToCapacity (/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x3f15)
    #3 0x101413e50 in NXHashInsert (/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x3e50)
    #4 0x101413b0d in NXCreateHashTableFromZone (/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x3b0d)
    #5 0x1014139ce in NXCreateHashTable (/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x39ce)
    #6 0x1014138ce in NXCreateMapTableFromZone (/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x38ce)
    #7 0x101413878 in NXCreateMapTable (/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x3878)
    #8 0x101412350 in __sel_registerName(char const*, int, int) (/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x2350)
    #9 0x101412062 in sel_init (/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x2062)
    #10 0x1014119ca in map_images_nolock (/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x19ca)
    #11 0x101424fe8 in map_images (/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x14fe8)
    #12 0x10003e03b  (<unknown module>)
    #13 0x10003e255  (<unknown module>)
    #14 0x10105f00a in _dyld_objc_notify_register (/usr/lib/system/libdyld.dylib:x86_64+0x300a)
    #15 0x101411074 in _objc_init (/usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib:x86_64h+0x1074)
    #16 0x100ff268d in _os_object_init (/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib:x86_64+0x168d)
    #17 0x100ff263a in libdispatch_init (/usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib:x86_64+0x163a)
    #18 0x100f069d5 in libSystem_initializer (/usr/lib/libSystem.B.dylib:x86_64+0x19d5)
    #19 0x10004ea1a  (<unknown module>)
    #20 0x10004ec1d  (<unknown module>)
    #21 0x10004a4a9  (<unknown module>)
    #22 0x10004a440  (<unknown module>)
    #23 0x100049523  (<unknown module>)
    #24 0x1000495b8  (<unknown module>)
    #25 0x10003b433  (<unknown module>)
    #26 0x10003f8c5  (<unknown module>)
    #27 0x10003a248  (<unknown module>)
    #28 0x10003a035  (<unknown module>)

Address 0x000104a001b0 is a wild pointer.
SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: bad-free (/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Toolchains/XcodeDefault.xctoolchain/usr/lib/clang/9.0.0/lib/darwin/libclang_rt.asan_osx_dynamic.dylib:x86_64h+0x59066) in wrap_free
==22900== Invalid read of size 4
==22900==    at 0x101416E7A: class_createInstance (in /usr/lib/libobjc.A.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x100FF276A: _os_object_alloc_realized (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x1013C8A73: xpc_dictionary_create (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x1013CC0AD: _bootstrap_create_request (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x1013CBE6E: bootstrap_look_up3 (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x1013CBE10: bootstrap_look_up2 (in /usr/lib/system/libxpc.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x101348A81: ___notify_lib_init_block_invoke (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x100FF28FB: _dispatch_client_callout (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x100FF28B8: dispatch_once_f (in /usr/lib/system/libdispatch.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x1013454F1: _notify_lib_init (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x101346386: notify_register_check (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_notify.dylib)
==22900==    by 0x1013A4448: _os_trace_prefs_and_mode_refresh_slow (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_trace.dylib)
==22900==  Address 0x10 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==22900==
ASAN:DEADLYSIGNAL
AddressSanitizer: nested bug in the same thread, aborting.
==22900==
==22900== HEAP SUMMARY:
==22900==     in use at exit: 208 bytes in 7 blocks
==22900==   total heap usage: 7 allocs, 0 frees, 208 bytes allocated
==22900==
[1]    22900 killed     valgrind --leak-check=yes ./tmpsh
```

Comment: `ImageLoader::runInitializers` <- This comes from some library initialization code; Looks, like the big allocation might be performed there.

Comment: I already have this kind of trouble and it seem to come from the OS, and valgrind could work with this kind of error (quit common actually).
  
(own question) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54671093/c-leak-on-fork-without-malloc

Can it make bigger allocation because of a specific configuration ?
Can I have access to initialization library?

Comment: If you have the source to that library, then yes. Try to _not_ link with the static library you mention and see, if the error persists

Comment: I tried what you said but it doesn't solve the problem actually. But I performed something else. I was compiling with `-g -fsanitize=address`. Removing `-fsanitize=address` solved my problem :) Thanks for your time.

Comment: How much RAM do you have on your system? `ptr = malloc(sizeof(struct test) * UINT_MAX);` attempts to allocate `sizeof(struct test) * 4294967295` bytes of memory. `sizeof(struct test)` is likely 32-bytes, so the total allocation is likely `137438953440` that is `131G+` and you are calling that in a `while` loop without a `free`?

Comment: I have 8 GB of Memory (Mac OS Sierra)

Comment: the sliver of posted code for a main() function will cause the compiler to output several warnings 1) unused parameter: `argc` 2) unused parameter: `argv`  3) variable `history` not used 4) type `t_hist` not defined.   hopefully, your actual code looks nothing like the snippet you posted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was compiling using `-g -fsanitize=address` flags. Removing `-fsanitize=address` did the job and allow me to use valgrind properly.

Feel free to add detail if you have any explaination.

Comment: what about the other options that should be on the compile statement(s), like `-Wall -Wextra -Wconversion -pedantic -std=gnu11`?  If your using `gdb` for debugging, then on both the compile statements and the linker statement the `-g` should be: `-ggdb` or even `-ggdb3`

Comment: suggest reading [-fsanitizer=address](https://github.com/google/sanitizers/wiki/AddressSanitizer)  especially: `The tool consists of a compiler instrumentation module (currently, an LLVM pass) and a run-time library which replaces the malloc function.`

Comment: valgrind and sanitizers (e.g. address sanitizers) are tools that are aimed at detecting the same kind of problems.  They typically cannot be run together.  So, to run valgrind on your program, your program should better be compiled *without* sanitizers.

Comment: @user3629249 I added -Wall -Werror (avoiding -pedantic and -Wconvertion, nothing relevant) and I get something like this when removing (single) uninitialized variable :
`==87636== Syscall param msg->desc.port.name points to uninitialised byte(s) `
`==87636==    at 0x10040334A: mach_msg_trap (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib)   `
.... (too long for comment)  
`==87636==  Address 0x1048a4c8c is on thread 1's stack  `
`==87636==  in frame #2, created by task_set_special_port (???:)`  
Not sure if it's my fault, I would say it's coming from my system.